# Swift Firestore Firebase map protocol to Array of Structs

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am making an app in swift with Firebase Firestore, the app is like medium and tumblr where users post blogs with different content. The problem I have is that I want to be able to have within my PostModel a field called attachments that contains a map of the url images, texts, headers, gifs, etc...

So I need an array that contains a protocol with the type of attachment and based on that, obtain the list of attachemnts with their respective struct models. The problem is that firebase doesn't accept protocols inside Codable structs.

```
struct PostModel: Identifiable, Codable {

    //MARK: - Data
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var attachments: [AttachmentsModel]

    //MARK: - CodingKeys
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case attachments
    }
}

//Attachments
enum Attachmentstype: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case caption = "caption"
    case header = "header"

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case caption
    }
}

protocol AttachmentsModel: Codable {
    var type: Attachmentstype { get }
}

struct CaptionAttachment: Codable, AttachmentsModel {
    let caption: String
    let type: Attachmentstype
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case caption
        case type
    }
}

struct HeaderAttachment: Codable, AttachmentsModel {
    let header: String
    let type: Attachmentstype

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case header
        case type
    }
}
```

Document:
[image: Firestor Document]

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to implement a custom decoding strategy